# Statically loading libraries not working in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I create a solution with 3 projects `A`, `B` and `C`.
Provided that `A` and `B` are libraries and `C` is a console Application

Where the reference usage is:

`A` uses `B`

`C` uses `A` and `B`

Why when I execute `C`, it loads `A` but fail to load `B` (Probably because it was already loaded through `A`)?

This is a typical issue in projects using libraries dynamic loading but in my case my libs are statically added to the reference so why is this happening?

I'm using .Net Core 3.0 preview 6 with Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.1.4)

Repo: https://github.com/hdkruswork/runes-dotnet/tree/dev

Where `A` is `Runes.Core`, `B` is `Runes.Async` and `C` is `Runes.Lab`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please provide with the code that you load the library and the exception thrown to make it possible to locate your problem?

Comment: I don't use any code to load the library, as it's referenced statically in the reference section in the project. The exception I get in runtime is FileNotFoundException (Couldn't load library `A` because system cannot find the file specified). Of course I checked the file was in the right output folder. Even more, I could load it dynamically, but my question is why it doesn't work statically.

Comment: You can only use `PackageReference`, `FrameworkReference` or `ProjectReference` instead of `Reference` on .NET Core.

Comment: @Alsein, I have it as a ProjectReference and it's not working.

Comment: Did C or A use any type defined in B statically? If not, I may have the answer

Comment: @Alsein If you meant whether C or A use statically a type from B, the answer is yes. If you meant whether C or A use a static class from B then the answer is not.

Comment: So B is ignored when the assemblies are loading.

Comment: Are you using B by reflection? If yes, you must provide with your code about this. Or if not, it would be meaningless if you use the types in B neither statically nor dynamically.

Comment: I use B explicitly (Not by reflection), I have B included in the Project references of A and C, but it's not working for C. Just updated the question with link to repo

Comment: BTW, anybody here could tell me how to improve the question? I ask because obviously down votes doesn't help on that regard.

Comment: After all, can you please paste your csproj files?

Comment: csproj files are in the repo

Answer (score 0):

If this is all within the same solution.. Remove all the references between the projects and re-add them

Comment: If all the projects are in the same solution; there should be no reason for your error. Are you able to upload the solution to Github for us to take a look at/replicate the problem?